# How to Show message from Runnable to the MainActivity

Tags: android

I am using the external library SignalR, and I find the Github code in Java I have implemented it successfully and receiving the Log messages such as Connected , Message etc but when I tries to show these messages in the MainActivity EditText and textviews , it is really not working . Following is a code that I modified according to my need now tell me how to modify accordingly in android to receive the messages on Ui.

```
public class HubClient  {
public HubProxy RelayServerHubProxy;
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
public HubConnection RelayServerHubConnection;
Context context = null;
public Boolean Connected = false;
public static String ErrorName,ConnectionStatus,MessageReceived;

Logger logger = new Logger() {

    @Override
    public void log(String message, LogLevel level) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // System.out.println(message);
        Log.v("Message Received in Logger", message);

    }
};

public HubClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    mainActivity = new MainActivity();
}

public void Connect(String ServerURI, String SockConnectionType) {

    try {

        ClientTransport webSockTransport = null;

        RelayServerHubConnection = new HubConnection(ServerURI);

        // creating hub prox object
        RelayServerHubProxy = RelayServerHubConnection
                .createHubProxy("MyHub");

        // Start the connection

        RelayServerHubConnection.start().done(new Action<Void>() {

            @Override
            public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("Connection Status", "Connection done");

            }
        });

        // Subscribe to the error event

        RelayServerHubConnection.error(new ErrorCallback() {

            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                error.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("WE've GOt erroe", error.getMessage());
                ErrorName = error.getMessage();
                //mainActivity.ShowToast(error.getMessage());


            }
        });

        // Subscribe to the connected event

        RelayServerHubConnection.connected(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.v("Connected", "Connected");

                Connected = true;
                // Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Connected",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        // Subscribe to the closed event

        RelayServerHubConnection.closed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("Connection is", "Closed");


            }
        });

        RelayServerHubProxy.subscribe(new Object() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void messageReceived(String name, String message) {
                Log.v("Server Message", name + message);
                // Toast.makeText(context, message,
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MessageReceived = name+message;

            }
        });

        // Subscribe to the received event

        RelayServerHubConnection.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(JsonElement json) {
                //how to show this message on again mainactivity Textview
                Log.v("onMessagReceived", json.toString());

            }
        });

        RelayServerHubConnection.stateChanged(new StateChangedCallback() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ConnectionState oldState,
                    ConnectionState newState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (newState == microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.ConnectionState.Connected)

                {
                    // how to show Connected status in Textview?

                } else if (oldState == microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.ConnectionState.Disconnected) {

                    // Show Message here
                }

            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void SendMessageToServer(String messageToServer1) {

    try {

        RelayServerHubProxy.invoke("MessageFromClient",
                (String) messageToServer1);

        RelayServerHubConnection.error(new ErrorCallback() {

            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                error.printStackTrace();
               //How to show message of error on Main Activity ?
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("Exception", e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

> Now I have commented what I want in the functions. Notice that All function is using Runnable . So please tell me how to modify this to use in android

Comment: you can use broadcast for that

Comment: how I can use broadcast for this ?

Comment: please show me just a sample code

Comment: let me read and apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show an alertDialog paste this function in your HubClient object:

```
private void showError(final String message) {
    ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Error")
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                .show();
        }
   });
}
```

You can call it inside your error callback

To show a message in a TextView use this one:

```
private void updateTextView(final String message) {
    ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // mTextView must be referenced by HubClient
            mTextView.setText(message);
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: ok I will test this , but what if I need to show the mesages in the listview?

Comment: Be careful...  casting Context to Activity is dangerous... Be sure to put an activity as first argument of HubClient's constructor.

Comment: I have done this in my constructor of hub client 
mainActivity = new MainActivity();

Comment: please tell me what do you mean by this , tell me , If my activity name is MainActivity , then how should I write this line ??

(Activity)context).runOnUiThread     in your answer

Comment: you can't allocate an activity in the way you did... MainActivity activity = new MainActivity() means nothing....

Comment: you can ignore "MainActivity activity = new MainActivity()"

Comment: then What do you mean by " Be sure to put an activity as first argument of HubClient's constructor."

Comment: use the context attribute.
if you allocated HubClient in this way:
    client = new HubClient(<an_activity>);
then you can go ahead and use the context attribute in your HubClient.

Comment: ihave done this way , the method you have posted :
private void updateTextView(final String message) {
     ((MainActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             // mTextView must be referenced by HubClient
             mainActivity.etIp.setText(message);
         }
    });
 }
 
and its working

Comment: but when I want to show toast it crashes up.  :

private void showToast(final String message) {
     ((MainActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             // mTextView must be referenced by HubClient
             Toast.makeText((Context)mainActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
    });
 }

Comment: Please, don't use your mainActivity in this way... an activity must be created through an Intent... you can't allocate an activity like an object.
Refer to the official documentation http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: ihave  changed to context now toast is also working , SO now it is safe ?

Comment: yes... if you allocated HubClient passing an activity as first argument it's safe ;)

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAA  i am stupid kid in android and I do not know What do mean by that "if you allocated HubClient passing an activity as first argument it's safe "  
you mean to say doing this   "hubClients = new HubClients( MainActivity.this)"  in my main Activity ? or something else?

Comment: don't forget my candy... XD

Comment: first argument in where ?
Take a look at my constructor of HubClient 

public HubClient(Context context){
  mainActivity = new MainActivity();
  this.context = context;
 }

Comment: hubClients = new HubClients( MainActivity.this) is correct